# There is something wrong with syntax highlighting of Meta component in Storybook

Tags: syntax, svelte, storybook, svelte-3

I use Svelte and Storybook.
The syntax highlighting in VSCode is wrong.
Storybook is working fine.

Is there any way to display syntax highlighting properly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That editor displays the syntax highlighting language in the bottom right corner: please update your screenshot to go up to the bottom right corner of the window.

Comment: The language in the lower right corner is Svelte.
Please check the screenshot.